# android setselection not working when parameter is variable for spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have tried many solutions but setSelection(position) does not work when
position is variable for spinner i.e. not constant.
Following are the approaches I have tried and all were written after setAdapter for spinner.
Also,I have checked pos variable value before call to this method which has value as expected however in all cases I'm getting default element of 0th position.

1)By using handler:

```
int pos=getPos();  // some method to return default position to be displayed for spinner

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            clinicListSpinner.setSelection(pos,true);
        }
    }, 100);
```

2)Setting animate parameter true:

```
clinicListSpinner.setSelection(position,true);
```

3)Setting animate parameter false:

```
 clinicListSpinner.setSelection(position,false);
```

4)Normal setposition call:

```
clinicListSpinner.setSelection(position);
```

Nothing worked for me on android 4.1

But it works well in all above cases when I send hard-coded or constant value to a variable

```
e.g. clinicListSpinner.setSelection(1,true);
```

I have searched a lot but did not get any solution to my problem please help me out.
    Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that the method `getPos()`is returning a correct item position? Because, if yes, there is no reason to your code not work.

Comment: Yes @bruno , I have checked pos value(inserted sysout after that) it returns required value but it does not select it